# Is it okay to build Arqade in Minecraft?

Tags: discussion, legal

I'm building a replica of this site in Minecraft. I need to know if I'm wasting my time. I would like to put a video of it on YouTube.

Before you say to yourself, "But you can't build a *website* in Minecraft!", I'm putting pixel art:

[image]

On the front (MBraedley's design, I give him credit in the map), and inside, rooms that have questions (and answers). Closed questions are literally closed (inside locked doors). Is this acceptable?

A little context: I'm building an adventure map with puzzles. A guide (Myrtle the Mushroom Man, I'm open to better name suggestions) will escort you to another puzzle, but can also bring you to Arqade, which has all the answers.

I'm not even sure that putting usernames is acceptable.

How far can I go with this?

Oh, and when I finish, I'll edit in a let's play link if you want to see it. If I'm allowed to.

If it's just a matter of making money off videos and therefore off Arqade, I can always turn monetization off.

Edit: I also wanted a Mothership boss battle that you had to flag as "off topic", but it wouldn't fit in with the rest. D:

Comment: As long as you don't actually claim it's in any way official, or that it is actually made by SE, you'll be fine.

Comment: When you do make it, please post a link to the world here for us all to see :)

Comment: Here's me imagining logging onto a Arqade and browsing questions by walking amongst rows of signs representing tags, navigating to a question - a large building where  the question is emblazoned on the front wall. Enter the building and there's one or more solutions built as contraptions. There's a few other people there editing them, fixing up some of the worse contraptions, modifying them to use a particular type of block instead of just dirt or cobblestone so that they look better.

Comment: @angussidney, Do you want a link to the whole let's play, or just the sites?

Comment: @RainbowDash Both, if possible

Comment: Well . . . This is going to take a while. See you in a year!

Comment: Thinking out loud: I guess it would be allowed to do this, provided the terms of the Creative Commons "with attribution" license (see link [legal](http://stackexchange.com/legal) at bottom of every StackExchange page) are fulfilled.  How would you link back to the originals?

Comment: "But you can't build a website in Minecraft!" - I think someone can create a full website in Minecraft, if someone really wants to.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not sure why you didn't insert a creeper in your description…

Answer (score 1):

For all StackExchange sites, user contributions are [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) while Stack Exchange Inc. (SEI) retains copyright on the site design and logo. This means:

1. User-submitted content can be used however you like, provided that appropriate [attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) is given and you also distribute the material under a CC-BY-SA license.
2. Usage of the site design or its logo must be coordinated/negotiated with SEI.

Comment: How do you suggest that I negotiate this with SEI?

Comment: @RainbowDash http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/contact